# QML Контейнер с автоматической компоновкой элементов по ширине/высоте

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

*Вопрос*:
Есть `Column Row` и `Grid` - три основных контейнера в qt. Они компонуют своё содержимое внутри себя в столбец, строку и таблицу соответственно.

*Задача*: вывести в контейнере 15-20 небольших однотипных элементов, но так, чтобы они не выходили за пределы контейнера при изменении его размера. т.е. если контейнер сужается по ширине, то в нём появляется больше строк и содержимое вытягивается в колонку, а если сужается по высоте, то наоборот - содержимое вытягивается в строчку.

По сути, код я реализовал. Всё на `qml`, всё работает. Но разве нету в qml подобного контейнера в стандарте? Я искал достаточно долго, но найти ничего не смог.

Может кто сталкивался с подобной задачей, поделитесь опытом.

Comment: [аналогичный вопрос с ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/999429/286405)