# Существует ли аналог "flexbox" в QML?

Tags: c++, qt, flexbox, qml, layout

Пишу приложение на C++ с применением библиотеки Qt. Для построения пользовательского интерфейса был выбран Qt Quick в связи с неплохой поддержкой сенсорных экранов. При написании программы возникла следующая сложность:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скажите пожалуйста, есть ли какая-либо компоновка, позволяющая расположить прямоугольники следующим способом так, чтобы при изменении размера окна они автоматически подстраивались под новое соотношение ширины/высоты? Похожей по желаемому поведению является следующая [верстка](https://jsfiddle.net/yxs1bmq6/), но встраивать WebView в конечный продукт совсем не хочется.

```
<style>
    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        align-content: space-around;
        background-color: aqua;
        height: 500px;
    }
    .box {
        background-color: green;
        padding: 50px;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
      box1
  </div>
  <div class="box">
      box2
  </div>
  <div class="box">
      box3
  </div>
  <div class="box">
      box3
  </div>
  <div class="box">
      box3
  </div>
  <div class="box">
      box3
  </div>
  <div class="box">
      box3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Flow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flow.html)

Comment: @vegorov Он, вроде бы, так же ведет себя совсем не очевидно. С моей точки зрения, это велосипед и с ним неудобно работать.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462117/flow-layout-with-centered-content

Comment: `Скажите пожалуйста, есть ли какая-либо компоновка, позволяющая расположить прямоугольники следующим способом так, чтобы при изменении размера окна они автоматически подстраивались под новое соотношение ширины/высоты?` Тем не менее под такую постановку вопроса он подходит. Я не говорю что он хорош. Можете отредактировать вопрос, описав недостатки `Flow`. Так более очевидно зачем понадобился `Flex` в Вашей реализации. Я, например, прочитал Ваш вопрос, ответа ещё не было или я не заметил, полез гуглить документацию и нашёл `Flow`, оставил ссылку. Я его не применял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего, не применяя WebView, оказалось написать привязки к библиотеке просчета компоновки компонентов от FaceBook из React Native - [Yoga Layout](https://yogalayout.com/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Созданный компонент позволил достаточно производительно рисовать flexbox. Обновление позиции дочерных элементов при изменении размера окна происходит плавно и без задержек.

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    height: 400
    width: 675
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "cyan"
        Flex {
            height: parent.height
            width: parent.width

            flexDirection: "row"
            flexWrap: "wrap"
            justifyContent: "spaceAround"
            alignItems: "center"
            alignSelf: "center"
            alignContent: "stretch"

            Rectangle { color: "green"; height: 150; width: 150 }
            Rectangle { color: "green"; height: 150; width: 150 }
            Rectangle { color: "green"; height: 150; width: 150 }
            Rectangle { color: "green"; height: 150; width: 150 }
            Rectangle { color: "green"; height: 150; width: 150 }
            Rectangle { color: "green"; height: 150; width: 150 }
            Rectangle { color: "green"; height: 150; width: 150 }
        }
    }
}
```

Исходный код данного решения опубликовал в свободном доступе в [соответствующем](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/qml-flexbox) репозитории.

Comment: В QML enum завезли, а в последних версиях QtCreator он даже поддерживается редактором qml файлов. Строки можно наверное заменить на значения из enum. Типа `flexDirection: Flex.Row`

Comment: @vegorov Для начала, Qt Creator должен как минимум обновиться в стандартных репозиториях всех популярных дистрибутивов Linux (в том числе Debian), чтобы qml файлы выводились корректно у всех. Даже без расширений для других IDE.